# Take DF1 Index and put it in DF2 as a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to put an index into another dataframe column :

```
DF1['NewCol'] = DF2.index
```

But this does throw :

```
ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```

Thing is that I am not even trying to reindex...

### Note

```
print(DF2.index)

Index(['A', 'A', 'A',
       'A', 'A', 'A',
       'A', 'A', 'A',
       'A',
       ...
       'B', 'B', 'B',
       'B', 'B', 'B',
       'B', 'B'],
      dtype='object', name='ID', length=3172)
```

---

```
DF1= pd.DataFrame()        
#DF1['NewCol'] = DF.index --THROW ERROR
DF1['Col1']  = DF.Col
DF1=DF1.merge(DF[['Col1','LEVEL_1']].rename(columns={'LEVEL_1': 'XX'}), on = 'Col1', how='left')
DF1['NewCol'] = DF.index #WORKING
```

Comment: What code return `ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels` ?

Comment: @ThePyGuy - it is same like `DF1['NewCol'] = DF2.index`, so it is something else

Comment: @jezrael without `DF1['NewCol'] = DF2.index` my code is executed throwing no error

Comment: But problem is in code after `DF1['NewCol'] = DF2.index`, not in `DF1['NewCol'] = DF2.index`

Comment: you should provide self-sufficient (minimal!) code that reproduces the issue. In short the minimal code for which, copying it in a new python shell gives the same error.

Comment: Problem is your code need unique value in `NewCol`, but if use `DF1['NewCol'] = DF2.index` create column with duplicates

Comment: @jezrael I have updated my post, hope you can help me to understand what is going on.

Comment: Because `DF1['Col1'] = DF.Col` is using the index to align, unlike `DF1['Col1'] = DF.index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work even if you have duplicates:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('MNOPON')}, index=list('XXYYZZ'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=list('AAABBC'))
df1['new'] = df2.index
```

output:

```
   A new
X  M   A
X  N   A
Y  O   A
Y  P   B
Z  O   B
Z  N   C
```

###### why your code failed:

`DF1['Col1'] = DF.Col` triggers the error as **it is using the index to align**, unlike `DF1['Col1'] = DF.index`, and your index is duplicated, which makes it ambiguous for pandas to know how to address the data